# Multiple Recaptcha on same page disappearing on failed submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have two ajax forms on a page that are both partial views.  Both have recaptcha and I can't seem to find a way for the recaptcha's to reload after the forms have been submitted and failed validation.

The Recaptcha's are loaded explicitly and I have two problems, firstly if I use:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

on both forms then I receive an 'Uncaught Error recaptcha placeholder element must be empty'.  So I can't do that.  If I put the above as loaded with the overall layout for the entire page I have my second problem which is that the recpatcha's will not reload once a form has been submitted incorrectly.

The script that loads each recaptcha is as follows:

```
var recaptcha1;
var recaptcha2;
var myCallBack = function () {

    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
        'sitekey': 'sitekeyhere', 
        'theme': 'light'
    });


    //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
    recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
        'sitekey': 'sitekeyhere', 
        'theme': 'light'
    });
```

The recaptcha's in the forms look like:

```
<div id="recaptcha1"></div>
```

I am using MVC 5, my controlller action for the form submit is something like this:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> FormSubmit(contactform model, string whichpage)
    {if (ModelState.IsValid && status)

        {*Updates database/sends email here*

else
        {

            return PartialView("_contactform", model);

        }
```

I've tried a variety of combinations where different things are loaded in different places but I can't find a combination which works with no errors.  What is the best way I can have both recaptcha's on their respective forms when either form has been submitted and failed validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue on form submissions via ajax. The issue was that when the form returns and calls the callback function, it wants to render both ReCaptchas in both forms. Since one ReCaptcha is already rendered, the other ReCaptcha breaks. To only render the ReCaptcha in the proper form, add the following `if` statements to check if the ReCaptcha was already rendered in the respected container. The example is using jQuery.

```
var myCallBack = function () {
  if($('#recaptcha1').is(':empty')) {
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
      'sitekey': 'sitekeyhere', 
      'theme': 'light'
    });
  }

  if($('#recaptcha2').is(':empty')) {
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
      'sitekey': 'sitekeyhere', 
      'theme': 'light'
    });
   }
}
```

You also need to make sure that both ReCaptcha placeholder elements are in the respected forms.

```
<form name="form1">
  [...]
  <div id="recaptcha1"></div>
</form>

<form name="form2">
  [...]
  <div id="recaptcha2"></div>
</form>
```